# MongoDB $match not working for part of sub document

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

In my **MongoDB**, I am trying to "*group by*" a set of records using the **aggregate()** function and the **$match** query I use does not select the records in the pipeline.

My dataset has sub documents (on which I apply the $match) and it looks like this:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("550994e21cba9597624195aa"),
    "taskName" : "task name",
    "taskDetail" : "task detail.",
    "scheduledStartDate" : ISODate("2015-04-06T09:00:00.000Z"),
    "scheduledEndDate" : ISODate("2015-04-06T11:00:00.000Z"),
    "user" : {
        "id" : "abcd1123",
        "name" : "username"
    },
    "status" : "Assigned"
}
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("550994e21cba9597624195aa"),
    "taskName" : "task name",
    "taskDetail" : "task detail.",
    "scheduledStartDate" : ISODate("2015-04-06T09:00:00.000Z"),
    "scheduledEndDate" : ISODate("2015-04-06T11:00:00.000Z"),
    "user" : {
        "id" : "abcd1123",
        "name" : "username"
    },
    "status" : "Assigned"
}
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("550994e21cba9597624195aa"),
    "taskName" : "task name",
    "taskDetail" : "task detail.",
    "scheduledStartDate" : ISODate("2015-04-06T09:00:00.000Z"),
    "scheduledEndDate" : ISODate("2015-04-06T11:00:00.000Z"),
    "user" : {
        "id" : "abcd1124",
        "name" : "username"
    },
    "status" : "Assigned"
}
```

I want to find out count of status for a particular user grouped by status type. For the user "abcd1123", the query that I use is:

```
db.tasks.aggregate( [
   {
       $match : {
           user : { id : "abcd1123" } 
       }
   },
   {
       $group: {
          _id: "$status",
          count: { $sum: 1 }
       }
   }
] )
```

The above query does not return any results, because the **$match** does not put any results into the pipeline. If I modify the query like this:

```
db.tasks.aggregate( [
   {
       $match : {
           user : { id : "abcd1123", name : "username" } 
       }
   },
   {
       $group: {
          _id: "$status",
          count: { $sum: 1 }
       }
   }
] )
```

it works. But I don't have the username as input and I need to find only based on user id.

Since user is not an array, I can't use **$unwind** on it.

How do I acheive this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are too close only change your aggregation query as below

```
db.collectionName.aggregate({
    "$match": {
    "user.id": "abcd1123"
    }
},
{
    "$group": {
    "_id": "$status",
    "count": {
        "$sum": 1
    }
    }
})
```